# Is $|X|$ always a random variable given that $X$ is one?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Is it true that $|X|$ is always a random variable given that $X$ is a random variable?

Comment: What is your definition of a random variable? Also, what exactly do you not understand here? Why is this question of interest to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the limited context of what you have provided, and from what I am inferring that you are asking, yes you are correct.

There is nothing random about the absolute value function, it is *completely deterministic*. Taking a variable $u$ and applying the absolute value function $|\cdot|$ to get the output $w$, that is $w = |u|$, the output $w$ is non-random.

However, the output of a function of a random variable $X$ *is random*, but that comes from the "randomness" of the random variable, not the function itself (which is completely deterministic). So if we take a random variable $X$, apply the absolute value function $|\cdot|$ to get the output $Y$, that is $Y = |X|$, the output $Y$ is random. Why? Because it is a function *of a random variable*.

Answer (score 0):

A [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) is a measurable quantity of our choice. For example, we can say `X` is a random variable that represents outcome of a dice roll. Similarly we can say `Y` is a random variable representing if the outcome of a dice roll is even. Its all about what you want to measure. As long as `X` is measurable `Y=|X|` is also a random variable measuring some other quantity (in this case absolute value of what `X` measures).

Answer (score -2):

Roughly saying, if you consider a variable $X$ such that $$\Pr\{X=x\}=\begin{cases}1&,\quad x=y\\0&,\quad x\ne y\end{cases}$$
then yes, the statement is true, unless counterexamples such as
$$
\Pr\{X=1\}=\Pr\{X=-1\}=0.5
$$
exist.